# JavaScript web app communicating with android app offline

Tags: javascript

I am newbie on this...
I have a javascript web app running on a windows 7 machine on Google Chrome.
And I have an Android app.
I want to establish connection offline (not over the internet) between them to send data.
They will both be connected on the same rooter or switch.

The windows 7 OS is not an option to change.

The question is what is the best web server to install in my case, so that the 2 apps (web app running on Chrome and the app running on Android device) will be able to communicate.

Solution based on the answer (correct me if I am wrong):

1. I will install nodejs server on the Windows Machine and I will create an event that will listen to a specific port in the local network for any new data to receive or deliver.
2. The android app will send new data to the specific port of the nodejs server and then the server will save the data.
3. My javascript web app that runs on Google Chrome Browser, will query the nodejs local server for any new data saved on the server.

Comment: How can there be offline communication?

Comment: I mean local communication, not over the internet. Of course both will be connected on the same rooter or switch.

Comment: I suppose your android device could listen for http requests from the chrome web app and process them.

Comment: Http requests locally not over the internet? Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: A web app is not a server. Is your Android app a server?

In any event you will need to know the IP address of both devices.

Comment: No the web app is not a server. Basically the question is if the web app could somehow act as a server and listen to some port of an IP that the Android app will send data to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a different approach.

If want you want is to be able to bind to a port and respond to requests consider installing node.js and covert your webapp into a node.js app.

[Here is a good resource for learning node](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/real-time-web-with-node-js)

Comment: Well this could be a solution but it is not so easy to do, as it probably needs to transform my whole web app and also install nodejs to each windows os. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you need to install node.js.

If my understanding is correct and you wish for your javascript code to act as a server, this is the way to go.

A standard browser contained web app cannot actively bind and listen to a port.

Comment: So installing nodejs in the windows platform would be better than installing a regular web server? Or the same thing?

Comment: The reason you suggest nodejs is because coding will eventually be easier as nodejs is based on js? What are the advantages?

Comment: Yes. Since his app is already javascript, nodejs would be the easiest env. That is really the primary advantage.

Comment: But it is also a fact that thweb server will not do anything more than transfer data between the android app and the web app. So I don't know if it worths it for this development.

Comment: web app is not a web server....web app is not a web server....web app...oh...never mind. :)

Comment: Sorry Maggini I might got something wrong. We have established that we need a web server to make the communication possible, because the web app cannot do it alone. So with a regular web server it wouldnt work? It would only work with nodejs server? Could you please elaborate on this? Thank you

Comment: it COULD work with a web server as an intermediary, yes.

However, since his code is ALREADY javascript, and nodeJS enables server-side javascript it seems like the path that would allow him the greatest re-use of his code.

So the code would still sit on the same Windows 7 machine, would still be javascript, but would run in a container that enables port binding and responding to requests from the smart phone.

Comment: OK, got it. But a question due to my lack of knowledge in nodejs... The web app will not continue running in Google Chrome?

Comment: The nodejs application could still serve up webpages (although if heavy serving of static resources is needed I would suggest something like an nginx front end with reverse proxy).

But yes, if all his use case requirements are satisfied by nodejs there is no need for a browser at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can install wifi share apps to your android device
they will connect your phone and pc over http protocol or install ftp server to pc or android device

Comment: Which do you think is the most robust choice given the fact that I will have a windows machine running the web app on Chrome browser and a custom made Android app?

Comment: @anestis explain more please , if in pc you have a web app which you want have access from android device you can install web sever to pc then define it on lan then you can access to web app from android device

Comment: This still does not solve his problem that a web app is not a server.

Comment: Do you mean change the PC os to a become a server? This is not a choice that I have. It should be done on windows 7 or XP os. The web app should be able to send and receive data from the android app. Two way communication. Being on the same local network.

Comment: @E.Maggini yes you are rigth , i didn't get what he mean by establishing connection between them , which type of connection ! sending which type of data

Comment: @anestis it is possible to build a web server on win 7 , 8 or xp and that's so easy , after building web server in your web app you can send and recive data

Comment: When OP is saying "web app" he means an application that sits in a web page. NOT an application built with JAVA, php or other...this is known by his use of the wording "javascript web app"....hence my suggestion to investigate node.js which will likely satisfy his requirements.

Comment: Yes Maggini is right about the web app running in JavaScript on a browser. So would it be possible for the web app to grab the data from the web server?

Comment: Yes a web app can talk to a web server, is the web server on the phone then?

Comment: No the phone that runs Android does not have a web server. It will have the app running. And the should be able to communicate somehow with the web server created in the windows machine. Will I need a static IP for this or will it work with the regular IP grabbed from the router or switch?

Comment: no android will not have web server , just pc will have it and in router you should define a static ip address for windows (pc)

Comment: you do not need a static IP. however, the phone will need to know the IP address in order to go to the correct place.

Comment: OK and after installing the web server, under which protocol will they communicate between them?

Comment: in web server over http protocol

Comment: Farhad when you say webserver you mean Apache?

Comment: yes , apache or you can use IIS